# Why doesn't CMake find Boost?

Tags: cmake, boost-unit-test-framework

i try to use Boost unit test framework to test my static library but CMake cannot find Boost in spite of `BOOST_ROOT, CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH, CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH` are set before call to `find_package`. Actually i've tried a lot of options based on the answers to similar question but still without any success.

**cmake version:3.6.1**

**boost version:1.60.0**

[Here is link to my project on GitHub](https://github.com/rokoDev/NetworkTest)

[And here is log output from TravisCI](https://travis-ci.org/rokoDev/NetworkTest/jobs/163770331)

CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION ${cmake_version})

project(${LibName}_test)

set(Boost_DEBUG ON)
set(Boost_DETAILED_FAILURE_MSG ON)

set(BOOST_ROOT $ENV{BOOST_ROOT})
message(STATUS "BOOST_ROOT >> ${BOOST_ROOT}")

set(BOOST_LIBRARYDIR $ENV{BOOST_ROOT}/lib)
set(BOOST_INCLUDEDIR $ENV{BOOST_ROOT}/include)

enable_testing()

set(Boost_USE_STATIC_LIBS       OFF)
set(Boost_USE_MULTITHREADED     ON)

SET(CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH ${CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH} "$ENV{BOOST_ROOT}/include")
SET(CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH ${CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH} "$ENV{BOOST_ROOT}/lib")

find_package(Boost 1.60.0 EXACT REQUIRED COMPONENTS unit_test_framework)

#if(Boost_FOUND)
    include_directories("${LIB_HEADERS}")


    add_executable(test_executable
                                main.cpp
                                SomeClass_test.cpp
                                )

    target_include_directories(test_executable PRIVATE ${Boost_INCLUDE_DIRS})

    target_link_libraries(test_executable
                                        #${Boost_UNIT_TEST_FRAMEWORK_LIBRARY}
                                        Boost::unit_test_framework
                                        ${LibName}
                                        )

    add_test(NAME test1 COMMAND test_executable)
#else()
#   message(STATUS "No Boost library were found!")
#endif()
```

main.cpp:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include <iostream>

// initialization function:
bool init_unit_test()
{
    return true;
}

// entry point:
int main(int argc, char * argv[]) {
    // insert code here...

    std::cout << "Boost version: "
    << BOOST_VERSION / 100000     << "."  // major version
    << BOOST_VERSION / 100 % 1000 << "."  // minor version
    << BOOST_VERSION % 100                // patch level
    << std::endl;

    return boost::unit_test::unit_test_main( &init_unit_test, argc, argv );
}
```

SomeClass_test.cpp:

```
#define BOOST_TEST_DYN_LINK
#include <boost/test/unit_test.hpp>

#include "config.h"
#include "Rectangle.h"
#include "SomeClass_test.hpp"

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(int_test)
{
    int i = 2;
    BOOST_TEST(i);
    BOOST_TEST(i == 2);

}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(area_test)
{
    Rectangle rect;
    rect.set_values(2, 3);
    BOOST_TEST(6 == rect.area());
}

BOOST_AUTO_TEST_CASE(config_test)
{
    auto major = SimpleNet::Version::Major;
    BOOST_TEST(0 == major);
}
```

Comment: Did you compile your boost?

Comment: @NulledPointer yes i did. `./bootstrap.sh --prefix=../installed/boost_${BOOST_UNDERSCORE_VERSION} --with-libraries=test
 ./b2 --layout=tagged -d0 link=shared threading=multi install` it is in before_install.sh file

Comment: You could setup `BOOST_ROOT`, `BOOST_LIBRARYDIR` and `BOOST_INCLUDEDIR` temporarily to make it work

Comment: @NulledPointer done it but CMake still failing to find Boost. Maybe CMake can't read Boost version because it says: **Imported targets not available for Boost version**?

Comment: What's your CMake version, what's your Boost version? CMake must be newer then your Boost, otherwise it cannot recognize it.

Comment: @usr1234567 i have edited my question and added CMake(3.6.1) and Boost(1.60.0) verstions. Also i've added definitions for `main.cpp` and `SomeClass_test.cpp`

Comment: @usr1234567 I have tried to use CMake 3.6.1 and 3.6.2(both must be aware about Boost 1.60.0) but without success.

Comment: @MikhailZinkovsky yes ignore `Boost_Find` also temporarily. It didn't work for me either and thats what i did. Ill dig into it more sometime later and will update this thread if I find the right answer.

Comment: @NulledPointer i've commented out checking `Boost_FOUND ` but this does not help.

Comment: @MikhailZinkovsky: When you use *REQUIRED* option with `find_package()` checking for `*_FOUND` variable is useless: If the package is not found, cmake terminates immediately.

Comment: @Tsyvarev you are totally right though this does not help to solve the main problem.